# Setting yAxis Max value in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/uKddL/7/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Jun']
    },

    yAxis: {
        max: 206,
        endOnTick: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 95.6, 54.4, 201]}]
});​
```

what can you do to make y-axis show 206!!

Answer (score 5):

The ticks have to be a multiple of the `tickInterval` value ... if you set the `tickInterval: 103` (or 51.5 ...) for the `yAxis` then you'll get your desired tick at 206.

Comment: got it .. this simply sets the intervals 
Thank you!